# How substituituion composition is associative?

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm not convinced that substitutions are associative, I read the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_(logic)#First-order_logic and the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cVNeccMF-E

My problem is in this case, I use $\Rightarrow$ to mean *reduces to*

$( f(X,Y)\{X \rightarrow Y\} )\{Y\rightarrow X\} \\
\Rightarrow f(Y, Y)\{Y\rightarrow X\}\\ \Rightarrow f(X, X)$

While

$f(X,Y)(\{X \rightarrow Y\}\{Y\rightarrow X\}) \\
\Rightarrow f(X,Y)\{X \rightarrow Y;Y\rightarrow X\} \\
\Rightarrow f(Y,X)$

I think my reduction understanding should be wrong but I don't know where.

Comment: I was revisiting this topic and managed to implement substitution correctly here, https://gist.github.com/dhilst/c69cdd5c3c144bd48c68f81422abac48

What I do is use a wrapping value to bookkeep the replacements so that I don't double replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have proven the composition $\{X\to Y\}\{Y \to X\}$ is not $\{X\to Y; Y\to X\}$.  Rather the composition is (assuming that it acts on terms to the left of it) $\{Y \to X\}$.

Also, that has nothing to do with associativity.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property.

Comment: _The composition of two substitutions σ = { x1 ↦ t1, …, xk ↦ tk } and τ = { y1 ↦ u1, …, yl ↦ ul } is obtained by removing from the substitution { x1 ↦ t1τ, …, xk ↦ tkτ, y1 ↦ u1, …, yl ↦ ul } those pairs yi ↦ ui for which yi ∈ { x1, …, xk }. The composition of σ and τ is denoted by στ. Composition is an associative operation, and is compatible with substitution application_ the composition seems correct to me, were is the error?

Comment: @geckos, You didn't apply that procedure correctly.  The composition is $\{X \to Y\tau; Y\to X\}$, not $\{X \to Y; Y \to X\}$, where $\tau=\{Y \to X\}$.  Note that $Y\tau = X$, so the composition is $\{X \to X; Y \to X\}$, which is equivalent to $\{Y \to X\}$, which is as I stated in the answer.  In any case, you have already shown that $\{X\to Y\}\{Y \to X\} \ne \{X\to Y; Y\to X\}$.

Comment: t1τ <--------------- there is a tiny little microscope tau there, OMG I hadn't see it before https://media.giphy.com/media/26ufdipQqU2lhNA4g/giphy.gif

Comment: Thank you so much @D.W for your patience!

Comment: @geckos, You're welcome!